# .net core usage of [HttpPatch] for bulk insert?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rest

is it possible to use httppatch for bulk data loading in a rest service? im using sqlkata in a ddd project wanted to test with a bulk, i'v been loking for method got this but i dont really undertand what do.

```
public class TransactionController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private DateTime Start;
    private TimeSpan TimeSpan;

    public TransactionController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SELECT records
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll([FromQuery] GetAllTransactionsParameter filter)
    {
        var data = await unitOfWork.Transactions.GetAllAsync(filter.PageNumber, filter.PageSize);
        return Ok(data);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SELECT a record by id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Transaction unique id</param>
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(Guid id)
    {
        var data = await unitOfWork.Transactions.GetByIdAsync(id);
        if (data == null) return Ok();
        return Ok(data);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// INSERT a record
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Transaction">Data fields for insert</param>
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Transaction transaction)
    {
        var data = await unitOfWork.Transactions.AddAsync(transaction);
        return Ok(data);
    }

    [HttpPatch]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(Guid id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Transaction> patchEntity)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpPatch` and JSON Patch is used to do the partial update. JSON Patch is a format for specifying updates to be applied to a resource. A JSON Patch document has an array of operations. Each operation identifies a particular type of change. Examples of such changes include adding an array element or replacing a property value.

For example,

The original response as below:

```
{
  "customerName": "John",
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderName": "Order0",
      "orderType": null
    },
    {
      "orderName": "Order1",
      "orderType": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, when we send a `HttpPatch` method with the following json patch document (sets the value of CustomerName and adds an Order object to the end of the Orders array.):

```
[  
  {  
    "op": "add",  
    "path": "/customerName",  
    "value": "Barry"  
  },  
  {  
    "op": "add",  
    "path": "/orders/-",  
    "value": {  
      "orderName": "Order2",  
      "orderType": null  
    }  
  }  
]
```

Then the response as below:

[image]

More detail information about using JSON Patch, see the following tutorials:

[JsonPatch in ASP.NET Core web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Json Patch (1) In ASP.NET Core web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-patch-in-asp-net-core-web-api/)

If you want to bulk insert items, you could use `HttpPost` or `HttpPut` method to send a list of items to the action method, and then insert them into database via the [DbContext.AddRangeAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addrangeasync?view=efcore-5.0).

Code like this:

```
    // POST api/<ToDoController>
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] List<Customer> customers)
    {
        //insert into database.
    }

    // PUT api/<ToDoController>/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] List<Customer> customers)
    {
    }
```